# How to get .crt and .key from cert.pem and key.pem

Tags: ssl, nginx

I know this is a super similar question to many other questions, but none of them either give a straight answer or one that works for me...

I have gotten two files from Let's encrypt:

- cert.pem
- key.pem

I need to get them into a `crt` and `key` format for use on an nginx server.

I have tried:

`openssl rsa -outform der -in key.pem -out key.key`

and

`openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out cert.crt`

but get the following error when starting up nginx:

```
# service nginx restart
Performing sanity check on nginx configuration:
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/nginx/cert.crt": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Extensions in file names do not count. PEM is an encoding format, it can be either a key or one (or more) certificates. You can rename `cert.pem` to `whatever.crt` and `key.pem` to `whatever.key` and things will work, no need to convert just rename the files if you want. There is no `crt` and `key` format. You have either binary (called DER) or Base64-encoded (PEM). BTW your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I had assumed I would needed to have formatted the keys differently. If you make your comment an answer I will mark it accepted. There are many cert/ ssl questions on this site so I thought it would be fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The extension `.pem` indicates that the file format is **PEM** (Privacy-Enhanced Mail). However, the extension does not tell anything about the content of the file. The content may be a certificate, a private key, a public key, or something else.

The extension `.crt` indicates that the content of the file is a certificate. However, the extension does not tell anything about the file format. The file format may be PEM, **DER** (Distinguished Encoding Rules) or something else. If the file is text and contains `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, the file format is PEM. On the other hand, if the file is binary, it is highly likely that the file format is DER.

The extension `.key` indicates that the content of the file is a private key. However, the extension does not tell anything about the file format. The file format may be PEM, DER or something else. If the file is text and contains `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` (or something similar), the file format is PEM. On the other hand, if the file is binary, it is highly likely that the file format is DER.

Diagrams below from *"[Illustrated X.509 Certificate](https://medium.com/@darutk/illustrated-x-509-certificate-84aece2c5c2e)"* illustrate relationship among **ASN.1** ([X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680/)), **DER** ([X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/)), **BASE64** ([RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)) and **PEM** ([RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468)).

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM]

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM (Application to X.509 Certificate]

Both `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` of `ngx_http_ssl_module` expect that the file format is PEM as the reference document says. Therefore, you don't have to change the file format of your `cert.pem` and `key.pem` because their file extension `.pem` indicates that their file format is already PEM. Just write like below in your Nginx configuration file.

```
ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem;
```

If you prefer `.crt` and `.key` extensions, just rename them like below.

```
$ mv cert.pem cert.crt
$ mv key.pem  key.key
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set up NGINX with Let's Encrypt, then you can do it automatically by using the application certbot.

**To install certbot for nginx:**

on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

on Arch linux:

```
sudo pacman -S certbot-nginx
```

on Centos:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install certbot-nginx
```

Then you need to make a very simple configuration file for your domain. The directory should be the same for all the mentioned operating systems

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

In here you just add this information:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000 #Example
        }
}
```

Then create the symlink to activate the domain

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

*Remember to change example.com with your domain, and switch proxy_pass to your service or directory of hosted files.*

Now you should restart NGINX:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

This one will return an error if you have errors in your configuration.

If everything is ok then restart NGINX

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Now certbot comes into the picture:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

At this point Let's encrypt will try to reach your nginx server, and if everything is OK - this means:

- Firewall settings allow for port 80 and 443 to pass
- Portforwarding throug network for the 2 ports are allowed

Then you will get to pick *easy* or *secure* access. I recommend the *secure* option.

When you have clicked [enter] then the process will be finished and certbot will have generated all your certification files and added them to the correct path.

Your configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-avalible/example.com` will have been updated with all the correct settings.

You may be required to restart nginx once again.

I hope it was helpful. Good luck

[Sources]

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Certbot#Nginx

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I already found a guide on this, just needed help on the format of the keys :)

Comment: My point was just that it is not necessary to manually format the keys :)